# What is the best to implement a column that increments with a SEQUENCE with CYCLE, has a MAXVALUE, and automatically uses UNIQUE values only?

Tags: postgresql

So I can achieve everything except the uniqueness like so:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_sequence 
MAXVALUE 5
CYCLE; 

ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN my_column int NOT NULL nextval('my_sequence');
```

I test this by inserting 5 records and deleting the third one, result in four records with 'my_column' set to 1, 2, 4, and 5.    What I want is to insert another my_table record and have the 'my_column' be 3, as that is the next "available" value.  Instead, it sets it to 1.

If I change the column to this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN my_column int UNIQUE NOT NULL nextval('my_sequence');
```

then it still tries to insert with the value of 1 in 'my_column' and throws a unique constraint error.

I understand why this works this way, that the sequence cannot possibly know the state of the table.  But how do I achieve this functionality?  Can it be done with serial?  can it be done at all?

Comment: Are you not worried what happens when all the possible values are used? If I understand you correctly you want to cycle the sequence values till you find the unused one. What if there is none left ?..

Comment: No, it can't be done with a sequence/serial.  What is the use case?